# Best way (easiest/fastest) to copy contents from an old EBS volume to new Nitro system EBS in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs

I have a really old m3 server (Ubuntu 14.04) that has a 300GB mounted EBS volume: `/dev/xvdf`. I also have a new m5 server (Ubuntu 18.04) that uses the Nitro system with a premounted EBS volume: `/dev/nvme1n1`. I tried unmounting then detaching the old EBS volume so I could attach and mount to the new server. However, that doesn't work as the instance ID doesn't show up during the `Attach Volume` screen in AWS console. It doesn't show up even if the new server has been turned off. I assume it's because of incompatibilities between the underlying AWS system for the servers.

That being said, I need to copy over the data from the old EBS to the new EBS. I read in a [different SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8885927/2464546) about making a 3rd instance where I can attach both. Then do a `rsync` between the two.  I don't think that'll work because of the mounting problem listed above. And I think that means I can't use AWS CLI either.

Both servers are in the same AZ. It's about 250GB of data that needs to be transferred.  I was going to do the naive approach of simply `scp` over ssh.

My Q is, is there a better way than `scp`?

Comment: rsync over ssh?

Comment: yeah, that's what i am going to go with. the old EBS is always being written to, so I can at least start rsync some time before actual cutover and do it a few other times to get the newer/updated stuff. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not to use [rsync](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) over ssh,
something like:

```sh
rsync -avzhe ssh --progress /mnt/nvme1n1 user@192.0.0.100:/mnt/rpmpkgs
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is just use recursive `scp`. Its not naive at all. Its the correct tool for the job imho. No need to sync,  use a 3rd instance, or `mount` commands. Just scp away!